# CMD reading paths from text file error

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a program which uses the batch file and the batch file uses the paths to files written in a text file.
I want the batch script to get whats written inside the text file (the paths) but instead, it gets the path to text file.

For example, a text file a path "D:\blabla" written in it and the texxt file is present in folder "C:\helllll". I want the script to read the path from text file (D:\blabla) but instead it reads "C:\helllll" (the location of text file).
basically, i want to read whats written inside a text file.
I am using following commands->

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set content=
for /F "delims=" %%i in ("path to text file\filename.txt") do set content=!content! %%i
ENDLOCAL
```

This should store whatever is written in the text file in a variable which i want to use. But instead, it read the path where text file is present and not what is written inside it!

Here is my complete script (its a part of a large program)->

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set fcontent=
for /F "delims=" %%i in (params5.enc) do set content=!content! %%i

set content=
for /F "delims=" %%i in ("LData\%fcontent%\params1.enc") do set content=!content! %%i

set content2=
for /F "delims=" %%i in ("LData\%fcontent%\params3.enc") do set content2=!content2! %%i

:UNLOCKER
set content3=
for /F "delims=" %%i in ("LData\%fcontent%\params4.enc") do set content3=!content3! %%i
echo %content%
echo %content2%
echo %content3%
pause
cd /d %content3%
attrib -h -s "%content2%.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "%content2%.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" "%content2%"
ENDLOCAL
exit
```

here, I only changed the extension of text file and I know that it doesn't affect anything as long as it is UTF-8 and contains only one line text.

Please help.

Comment: That's because you're telling it to read it as a string. You need to remove the quotes to have it read it as a file set or add "usebackq" if the path contains spaces.

Comment: yeah the path contains spaces, can you please provide with some example on how to use "usebackq"? The syntax?

Comment: for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("path to text file\filename.txt") do set content=!content! %%i

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to use the files, but try this one:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (' type "path to text file\filename.txt" ') do set "content=!content! %%i"
```